# Why does this code run for VS but not gcc/g++?

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a Red Black Tree using VS 2019 as my IDE. It seems to work in VS but when I try to  compile and run using anything else, it results in a seg fault whenever my insert function is called more than once. (I've tried online compilers and sending it to a friend) I'm stuck as I don't know where to start trying to fix my error. I've heard that VS handles dynamic memory differently but I'm not too sure.

Below is my rotate, BST insert and insert functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// default constructor
// creates empty tree, root is nullptr

class NodeT
{
public:
    // public variables
    double key;
    double value;
    NodeT* left;
    NodeT* right;
    NodeT* parent;
    bool isBlack;

    // constructors
    NodeT()
    {
        key = 0;
        value = 0;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;
        isBlack = false;
    }
    NodeT(double keyset, double valueset, bool isBlackset)
    {
        key = keyset;
        value = valueset;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;
        isBlack = isBlackset;
    }
};

class RedBlackTree
{
public:

    // default constructor, sets all to null
    RedBlackTree();

    // insert
    // inserts the first parameter key, and value second parameter into the tree
    // returns true if done, false if there are duplicates, dont insert
    bool insert(double insert_key, double insert_value);

    
public:
    NodeT* root;
    void leftrotate(NodeT* to_rotate);
    void rightrotate(NodeT* to_rotate);
    bool bstinsert(NodeT* insert);

};

RedBlackTree::RedBlackTree()
{
    root = nullptr;
}


void RedBlackTree::leftrotate(NodeT* to_rotate)
{
    NodeT* new_parent = nullptr;
    new_parent = to_rotate->right;
    to_rotate->right = new_parent->left;
    if (new_parent->left != nullptr)
    {
        new_parent->left->parent = to_rotate;
    }
    new_parent->parent = to_rotate->parent;
    if (to_rotate->parent == nullptr)
    {
        root = new_parent;
    }
    else if (to_rotate == to_rotate->parent->left)
    {
        to_rotate->parent->left = new_parent;
    }
    else
    {
        to_rotate->parent->right = new_parent;
    }
    new_parent->left = to_rotate;
    to_rotate->parent = new_parent;
}

void RedBlackTree::rightrotate(NodeT* to_rotate)
{
    NodeT* new_parent = to_rotate->left;
    to_rotate->left = new_parent->right;
    if (new_parent->right != nullptr)
    {
        new_parent->right->parent = to_rotate;
    }
    new_parent->parent = to_rotate->parent;
    if (to_rotate->parent == nullptr)
    {
        root = new_parent;
    }
    else if (to_rotate == to_rotate->parent->right)
    {
        to_rotate->parent->right = new_parent;
    }
    else
    {
        to_rotate->parent->left = new_parent;
    }
    new_parent->right = to_rotate;
    to_rotate->parent = new_parent;
}

bool RedBlackTree::bstinsert(NodeT* insert)
{
    NodeT* parent = root;
    NodeT* search = root;

    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = insert;  
    }
    else
    {
        while (search != nullptr)
        {
            parent = search;
            if (insert->key < parent->key)
            {
                search = parent->left;
            }
            else if (insert->key > parent->key)
            {
                search = parent->right;
            }
            else                
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (insert->key < parent->key)
        {
            parent->left = insert;
            insert->parent = parent;
            return true;
        }
        else if(insert->key > parent->key)
        {
            parent->right = insert;
            insert->parent = parent;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool RedBlackTree::insert(double insert_key, double insert_value)
{
    NodeT* y = nullptr;
    NodeT* x = new NodeT(insert_key, insert_value, false);
    bool dupe = bstinsert(x);
    if (dupe == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    while (x != root && x->parent->isBlack == false)
    {
        if (x->parent == x->parent->parent->left)
        {
            y = x->parent->parent->right;
            if (y == nullptr || y->isBlack == true)
            {
                if (x == x->parent->right)
                {
                    x = x->parent;
                    leftrotate(x);
                }
                x->parent->isBlack = true;
                x->parent->parent->isBlack = false;
                rightrotate(x->parent->parent);
            }
            else if (y->isBlack == false)
            {
                x->parent->isBlack = true;
                y->isBlack = true;
                x->parent->parent->isBlack = false;
                x = x->parent->parent;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            y = x->parent->parent->left;
            if (y == nullptr || y->isBlack == true)
            {
                if (x == x->parent->left)
                {
                    x = x->parent;
                    rightrotate(x);
                }
                x->parent->isBlack = true;
                x->parent->parent->isBlack = false;
                leftrotate(x->parent->parent);
            }
            else if (y->isBlack == false)
            {
                x->parent->isBlack = true;
                y->isBlack = true;
                x->parent->parent->isBlack = false;
                x = x->parent->parent;
            }
        }
    }
    root->isBlack = true;
    return true;
}
```

Calling this in main results in an seg fault except when in VS:

```
int main()
{
    RedBlackTree test;
    test.insert(47, 1);
    test.insert(32, 2);
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using debugger to step through your `insert` member function, to see what's going on? VS has a built in debugger for Windows

Comment: @Kaldrr Yes, on VS I can't see anything wrong, I can insert nodes and they seem to work fine. Inserting more than one node on another compiler is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  This means we should be able to take your code, and with no changes whatsoever, duplicate the issue.  Right now, we have no idea what the constructor for `RedBlackTree` does or does not do.

Comment: This looks slightly suspicious: `if (x->parent == x->parent->parent->left)` in the insert() function. Are you sure that the parent two levels deep is *always* initialised? (I can't see the code the populates it) and it *could* be undefined/null. Otherwise we are going to need the complete code. What compilers does this fail on? - for example in linux with gcc you can use an IDE like vscode + gdb to debug it.

Comment: More than likely those pointers are not initialized.  If so, the Visual Studio version is also broken.  Maybe if you ran a release version, you will see that there is a problem.

Comment: I've added the NodeT class and the functions in RedBlackTree that are used by insert.

Comment: `// default constructor, sets all to null` -- Why did you leave the constructor of `RedBlackTree` out of the posted code?

Comment: Also, did you not see the warning that Visual Studio gave you about the `bstinsert` function:  `warning C4715: 'RedBlackTree::bstinsert': not all control paths return a value`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry about that I must have forgot. I updated the original question with the constructor but I don't think its too interesting.

Comment: It is very important that it is there, because without it, we have no idea if you really initialized the member variables.  Just writing a comment means nothing, as comments many times do not tell the truth -- only the code tells the truth.

Comment: I thought the return was just a true or false value in this case, and it wouldn't cause a issue like this one.

Comment: No.  If a function is supposed to return a value, then the function **must** return a value, else the behavior is undefined.  Even the compiler warned you about it -- don't ignore the warnings.  If someone were to ask you what is returned, and your answer is "I don't know" -- well that's a problem, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one error that causes undefined behavior:

The `RedBlackTree::bstinsert` function fails to return a value when it is supposed to return a `bool`.

To verify this is the error, a line right before the end of the `bstinsert` function can be placed to verify that this is an error.

```
bool RedBlackTree::bstinsert(NodeT* insert)
{
    NodeT* parent = root;
    NodeT* search = root;

    if (root == nullptr)
    {
        root = insert;
    }
    else
    {
        while (search != nullptr)
        {
            parent = search;
            if (insert->key < parent->key)
            {
                search = parent->left;
            }
            else if (insert->key > parent->key)
            {
                search = parent->right;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (insert->key < parent->key)
        {
            parent->left = insert;
            insert->parent = parent;
            return true;
        }
        else if (insert->key > parent->key)
        {
            parent->right = insert;
            insert->parent = parent;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "This is undefined behavior\n";  // <-- add this line
}
```

You will see that the `std::cout` line will be encountered to confirm that you are returning from `bstinsert` without returning a value.

Also, the compiler you're using (Visual Studio), would have given a warning to you about this issue.  Something similar to this:

```
warning C4715: 'RedBlackTree::bstinsert': not all control paths return a value
```

You should not have ignored this warning.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that to actually compile and run something like this means the OP is intentionally ignoring diagnostics output by the compiler. Compilers generally complain when faced with functions that fail to return a value of the declared type `:)`

Comment: Ah. I thought I tested bstinsert so I didn't think it was the problem. I think bstinsert now returns the correct value, and now I have a reproducable error in the main insert function that I can try to fix now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @K.Lo FYI -- Don't fix the code and recompile it in release mode and run it.  You should see an exception thrown.  This is exactly what is meant by undefined behavior.